# LNK2001 DirectShow 64bit compilation in QtCreator

Tags: c++, qt, directshow, qmake

I get these errors showing up when compiling a Qt app in QtCreator.

```
link /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /DEBUG /OPT:REF /INCREMENTAL:NO 
/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS "/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY:type='win32' 
name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' 
publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*' processorArchitecture='*'" 
/MANIFEST:embed /OUT:..\AV\Setup\AV4.exe @C:\Users\me\AppData\Local
\Temp\AV4.exe.4516.30906.jom
capture.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol IID_ICreateDevEnum
capture.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol IID_IBaseFilter
samplegrab.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol IID_IBaseFilter
capture.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol IID_IGraphBuilder
capture.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol IID_ICaptureGraphBuilder2
capture.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol IID_IMediaControl
capture.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol IID_IMediaEvent
capture.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol IID_IVideoWindow
capture.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol MEDIATYPE_Video
samplegrab.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol MEDIATYPE_Video
capture.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol CLSID_CaptureGraphBuilder2
capture.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol CLSID_FilterGraph
capture.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol CLSID_SystemDeviceEnum
capture.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol CLSID_VideoInputDeviceCategory
capture.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol PIN_CATEGORY_PREVIEW
samplegrab.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol MEDIASUBTYPE_RGB24
samplegrab.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol IID_ISampleGrabber
samplegrab.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol CLSID_SampleGrabber
samplegrab.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol CLSID_NullRenderer
..\AV\Setup\AV4.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 17 unresolved externals
```

My question is of course, why? These are strmiids.lib errors but it is linked.
I think it may be because I want to compile this app for 64-bit, but strmiids was compiled 32 bit. There are no errors for gdiplus though and I don't know of a 64-bit DShow version.

```
LIBS += -L"C:/Users/me/AV/DShow/DShow/lib/x86"  -lstrmiids -lgdiplus -lWinmm
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/DShow/include
```

Comment: Long shot: you only have 32-bit .LIB on the path; the library is found but effectively ignored, hence the errors.

Comment: I should startpage this, but are there 64-bit direct show libs? How else can I compile a 64-bit app with 32-bit libraries?

Comment: For example, 64-bit strmiids.lib with the mentioned in question symbols is installed with latest Windows SDK here: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.14393.0\um\x64\strmiids.lib